# Ошибка с горизонтальным слайдером (Jquery-UI, AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Сразу скажу, только в Mozilla Firefox присутствует данная ошибка.
Ссылка на сайт: http://vklad.ru/poisk-vkladov/
Если двигать ползунок, то сумма в `input` меняется и контент подгружается без проблем. При вводе суммы в данное поле вручную, пропадает `focus` данного input'а и ползунок больше не двигается мышкой. Если кликнуть на него, то в консоли вылезает ошибка:

> TypeError: closestHandle is undefined

И указывает, что она находится в jquery-ui.js (что меня уже смущает).
Как можно решить данную проблему? Не имею представления даже куда копать.

Comment: версия jquery возможно

Comment: Версия jquery или jquery-ui?

Comment: и та и другая смотреть совместимости нужно, или подключить библиотеку noconflict

Comment: Все версии обновлены, все ок с этим. Больше склоняюсь к тому, что проблема из-за аякса и при обновлении контента что-то сбивается.

Answer (score 1):

Была подобная проблема, попробуйте эти сборки:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js
```